# Adding rows for recordsets that have incomplete date ranges

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This one is tricky for me, can't figure it out.

We have a system where we calculate inventory numbers on the fly.  If there's a month where a customer doesn't have any orders, there's no record for that month but the beginning inventory is still calculated and displayed as a rolling calculation based on the previous transaction data.

I'm now pulling this data but need to "fill in the blanks" so to speak.

For example, the table has the following fields:

```
MonthYear DATETIME
WarehouseID INT
Quantity DECIMAL(18,2)
```

If I put all this in a temporary table to do calculations, I'll end up with something like this:

```
2010-01-01 00:00:00.000 135 1000.00
2010-04-01 00:00:00.000 135 2000.00
2010-07-01 00:00:00.000 135 3000.00
2010-06-01 00:00:00.000 235 1000.00
2010-07-01 00:00:00.000 235 2000.00
2011-02-01 00:00:00.000 135 1000.00
2011-03-01 00:00:00.000 135 2450.00
```

etc., etc.

What I need to do is for each warehouse, if a record exists for that year, add a blank row for any months that aren't in the table.

In the example above for warehouse 135 I need to add a record for 02, 03, 05, 08, etc.

Is there any easier way of doing this rather than with cursors and loops?

Thanks.

Comment: You want to make up data or do you just don't know how to `JOIN` to complete your date range?

Comment: I need to make up data.  A record for 2010-02-01 135 doesn't exist but I need to have one for this specific purpose.

Comment: You shouldn't be making up data.

Comment: "making up data" is the wrong term to be using here.  I need to create blank records for month/years that don't have any transactions so I can carry over beginning inventory numbers from the previous month for aggregate reporting uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search `Recursive CTE`. Then LEFT JOIN. Gotta bolt out the door. Sorry for quick answer.